# How to set proper width to Stepper in Xamarin.Forms on Windows Phone

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Stepper in an ItemTemplate and it looks very odd on Windows Phone.

If I don't set any `WidthRequest`, it occupies most of the screen (why?).
If I set, the Stepper is cut and visible only partially.

This is the XAML:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Stepper Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="1"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    Increment="1"
    Maximum="50"
    Minimum="0"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    Value="{Binding MyValue}" />
```

This is how it looks on Android (completely good):

[image]

This is how it looks on Windows Phone (auto sized):

[image]

This is how it looks on Windows Phone (fixed sized - 100):

[image]

What should I do to make the + and - sign visible on Windows Phone?

Comment: You could try to set for middle column, something like `<ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />`

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy Same problem, the Stepper is cut if the column is shrinked.

Comment: And if set `0.4*, 0.3*, 0.3*` respectively to each `ColumnDefinition Width=`?

Comment: @EgorGromadskiy Same problem, the Stepper is still cut.